# I have an issue with running another Python file with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, hyperlink

I am trying to link my code that runs motors from tkinter condition. I didn't get any methods to do so.

I have tried hyperlink method, but it only opens the file on my browser.

...python

```
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser

def callback(url):
    webbrowser.open_new(url)

root = Tk()

link1 = Label(root, text="Running Hyperlink", fg="blue", cursor="hand2")

link1.pack()

link1.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: callback(r"/home/pi/ROBOT/pdf folder/GUIfunal1.py"))


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: welcolme de SO! For you'r next question, please considerer looking at : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Especially, don't add useless info in the title like "please help me"

Answer (score 0):

The statement `webbrowser.open_new(url)` opens the python script on the browser, but does not run it.

Without setting up a `Flask` server and loading the python script to the server, a python script will not be run. (There might be other ways, but Flask server is the one I know of).
If you do not want to hyperlink it, running it like `exec('path to python file.py')` should run it.

Comment: I got following errot when i used the exec command                                      
   Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/pi/ROBOT/GUIfunal1.py", line 26, in Table3
    exec('/home/pi/ROBOT/toolbar.py')
  File "<string>", line 1
    /home/pi/ROBOT/toolbar.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: clearly its a syntax error. These can be easily cleared by looking up the syntax on Google